# $G=(\mathbb{R}^*,\cdot)$ , $N=\{-1,1\}$. prove that $G/N\cong (\mathbb{R}_+,\cdot)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Let $G=(\mathbb{R}^*,\cdot)$ and $N=\{-1,1\}$. I need to prove that $G/N\cong (\mathbb{R}_+,\cdot)$

This is all the details that I have in the exercise, usually given  $\varphi$ such that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, but here how colud I prove the isomorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute value is a map from the non-zero reals to the positive reals that  conveniently is also a homomorphism with respect to multiplication.

Some further details need to be checked, which I do not spell out.